# ASP.NET MVC mix Razor and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

How can we pass a JavaScript variable to Razor code?

Here I have a simple tabs

```
<div id="AboutDoctor" style="min-height:34vh;">
<div class="row text-center text-primary">@MEDONET.Language.Doctor.Texts.About</div>
<div class="col-xs-2">
    <!-- required for floating -->
    <!-- Nav tabs -->
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs tabs-left">
        <li><a href="#_Info" data-toggle="tab" onclick="GetTabPane('_Info')">@MEDONET.Language.Doctor.Texts.Info</a></li>
        <li><a href="#_Diplomas" data-toggle="tab" onclick="GetTabPane('_Diplomas')">@MEDONET.Language.Doctor.Texts.Diplomas</a></li>
        <li><a href="#profile" data-toggle="tab">@MEDONET.Language.Common.Texts.Licenses</a></li>
        <li><a href="#messages" data-toggle="tab">@MEDONET.Language.Doctor.Texts.Summary</a></li>
        <li><a href="#settings" data-toggle="tab">@MEDONET.Language.Common.Texts.Reviews</a></li>
        <li><a href="#_Contacts" data-toggle="tab" onclick="GetTabPane('_Contacts')">@MEDONET.Language.IndexTexts.Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-9" style="margin-top:3vh">
    <!-- Tab panes -->
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane" id="_Info">@MEDONET.Language.Common.Texts.Loading...</div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="_Diplomas">@MEDONET.Language.Common.Texts.Loading...</div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="profile">Licenses</div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="messages">Summary</div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="settings">Reviews</div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="_Contacts">@MEDONET.Language.Common.Texts.Loading...</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And  by clicking on the tabs user invokes the GetTabPane() function and passes name of the function to it. The function by itself looks like this:

```
 function GetTabPane(val) {
    $('#'+val).load("@Url.Action("val", "Doctors", new { id = Model.Id })",
        function () { $('#'+val).tab-pane('show') });
 }
```

Almost all are work except the piece where I'm trying to pass the val as the action name

> ...Action("val",...

**So how  it can be to pass a JavaScript value to Razor inside the script block?**

Comment: Nope, you can't do `Url.Action` with JS variable. The only way to do is combining the JS variable in standard URL (e.g. `"/Doctors/" + val + "/id=...`), or using AJAX call to retrieve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not pass a JavaScript value to Razor. The reason is when in the page page life cycle the code is executed:

- Razor code is executed **on the server** before the page is returned to the client
- JS code is executed **on the client** after the page was returned

But you can solve your concrete problem by creating the URL initially with a placeholder, then replace it in the JS code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var urlPattern = '@Url.Action("__ACTION_NAME_TO_BE_REPLACED__", "Doctors", new { id = Model.Id })';

function GetTabPane(val) {
    var url = urlPattern.replace('__ACTION_NAME_TO_BE_REPLACED__', val);
    $('#'+val).load(url, function () { $('#'+val).tab-pane('show'); });
}
</script>
```

Comment: Glad to help :)